# Match function in unix to find if string ends with particular input value?

Tags: unix, awk

I need a regular expression that I can use in `match()` function to see if value given at command line argument exists at the end of a given string.

I am using `awk` then trying use `match` function to get above result:

```
while read line; do 
    cat $line | awk -v value="$2.$" '{ if ( match("$1,value) != 0 ) print match("arvind","ind.$") " " "arvind" }' 
done < xreffilelist.txt
```

Comment: Show us the file? regex logic? output expected?

Comment: file xreffilelist.txt cotains like /u1/test/list/apicall.p
                     /u1/test/list/apitest.p

Now I am giving "call" from command line 

while read line
do
cat $line | awk -v value="$2.$" '{ if ( match("$1,value) != 0 ) print match("arvind","ind.$") " " "arvind" }'

done < xreffilelist.txt

Comment: Pls edit your post with this, it is not useful in a comment.

Comment: Firstly, your `awk` code has an extra doble quote.

Comment: Secondly, `value="$2.$"` uses the value of the **second argument passed to your bash script** to set the value of  the `awk` variable `value`.

Comment: Why are you using the shell to feed `awk` one line at a time?  Awk can read files and process them line at a time all by itself.